# Restricting device to download apps other than my app from google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I developed an android app and provided Android devices to the users to access this App. I want  these phones will only update my application and user should not be able to download other apps from Google play store . Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: you can not restrict device base download in play store.

Comment: May be using rooting device